# call external php file from shopify registration page

Tags: php, api, shopify

i've been searching around for a way to call a php file on either the login or registration page of shopify.

I need to connect to another system and validate my users details and then if the users is a valid member assign the wholesale tag to the member otherwise they should remain a normal shopper.

I've tried ajax but I forgot about 'cross domain' calls so that did not work.
I've also started to read up on shopify apps but it seems to be used mainly to interact with the shops database and not with external scripts or am i missing something.

What i want to do is take my users login details, do a quick checkup if they are wholesale members and then update their tag before they register.

or would it be better to perhaps have my registration page outside of shopify and perhaps do what i need with the details and then try to register the users using an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after looking into webhooks and almost getting what i needed from that it feels as if the API will be the only way forward.

When using webhooks and the Customer creation event i received a lot of info that i needed, but for me to verify the users i needed both their UN and PW and for webhooks just did not supply that for me.

So i will update my registration.liquid page to basically be a container for my iframe.

if you could save info from the registration page as meta data you might be able to use webhooks to receive the user's ID and then do a call to the system and get the metadata, but from what i could see you can only create and view metadata via API.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple pattern. Install an App in the store. Your server, running PHP. Set that App to listen to the webhook for new customers. When that hits your server, validate the credentials inside your server. If the customer deserves a tag, you can now use the API to add that tag to the customer.

Simple. Secure. If you want to use some form of Ajax, that is also possible, using the App Proxy pattern.

So there are two solid correct answers for you. Curl? Seriously?

Comment: Thank you David, I will try our your webhook suggestion.
i will read up on it and see how it works.

otherwise i'm going to put a new registration form in an iframe and just use the API to create a new user.

Comment: I know it's old (and not accepted) answer, but you give me a hint that I'm gonna (probably) use in my shopify app. So at least I can give you an upvote.

Comment: It is true. Not many people would know an acceptable answer if it hit them in the face. Too many beginners in here... not enough veterans. Thanks for your vote though, it was the right thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Use curl or sockets for access to remote script

curl may store user cookies

Comment: thank you Michael, but as i said to WalkingRed, i'm already using curl to all  the other system form my php script. My problem is that i cannot call my php script from shopify. As far as i can see it does not support php.

Comment: i think you can only use shoify api, if you found need function, of, you can write to shopify support and ask them your question